# bash run commands for a period of time

Tags: bash, time

I am trying to using system time in bash to run a few commands. 
Here's a simplified version that I tried

```
echo $(date +%s); while [ $(($(date +%s)+10)) -gt $(date +%s) ]; do echo $(date +%s); done
```

I add 10secs to current time and print the time inside the while loop. 
What I see is the program runs for more than 10secs and I have to hit ctrl+C to stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check if the current time + 10 seconds is greater than the current time in your loop. That will always be true. It's the same as doing `while (( (X+10) > X ))`

You could instead calculate the endtime before starting the loop and use that in your comparison:

```
starttime=$(date +%s)
(( endtime = starttime + 10 ))

echo "$starttime - $endtime"

while (( endtime > $(date +%s) )); do
    date +%s
done
```